# PySimpleGUI program ends with warnings

Tags: python, pycharm, console, pysimplegui

when I execute the code below, it runs well with no issues. but when I try to close the GUI window directly through my PyCharm stop button it shows a traceback alert of multiple lines.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

label = sg.Text('this is my first GUI')
add_button = sg.Button('add')
user_input = sg.InputText(tooltip='enter something here')
window = sg.Window('Hello world', layout=[[label, user_input, add_button]])


window.read()
window.close()
```

I wanna get rid of this warning message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\gui.py", line 9, in <module>
    window.read()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 10075, in read
    results = self._read(timeout=timeout, timeout_key=timeout_key)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 10146, in _read
    self._Show()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 9886, in _Show
    StartupTK(self)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 16935, in StartupTK
    window.TKroot.mainloop()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1458, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to remove the stack trace for a keyboard interrupt. The reason it shows up is because it is signaling that the code was interrupted by the user and could not execute till the end. You can reproduce this when calling your program from a command line and pressing `ctrl+c`.

Anyways, if you want to silence an error, you can use a `try` `except` statement like so:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from sys import exit

def window():
    label = sg.Text('this is my first GUI')
    add_button = sg.Button('add')
    user_input = sg.InputText(tooltip='enter something here')
    window = sg.Window('Hello world', layout=[[label, user_input, add_button]])

    window.read()
    window.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        window()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)
```

I hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I think that PyCharm raises a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception which is fine.

if you still want to get rid of it you can handling it with:

```py
try:
    **YOUR CODE CALLED AS A FUNCTION**
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    raise SystemExit
```